# How can I use Mylyn to aid in JavaScript and Python development? How about HTML/CSS/JSP pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, mylyn

I installed and got acquainted with Mylyn today. I also watched the excellent Mylyn/Tasktop [webcast](http://tasktop.com/videos/mylyn/webcast-mylyn-3.0.html).

It's obvious how you can add individual packages, classes, interfaces, methods, etc. to a task's context in Java... but what about when using JavaScript or Python? How about HTML/CSS/JSP pages? Could Mylyn somehow add only certain JavaScript functions or objects to the current context? (other than the option to add the files themselves to the current context). The webcast mentioned the DLTK plugin works with Mylyn and supports dynamic languages briefly but not much more that that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [EclipsePedia](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Extensions), you'll find a list of Mylyn extensions and bridges. The [DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) is the only one listed there for Javascript. Install instructions can be found from within the [DLTK site](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/install.php).

From the DLTK site:

> Besides a set of frameworks DLTK provides exemplary Tcl, Ruby, Javascript and Python development environments ready to use out of the box.

You can find out some more information from the [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DLTK).

For Python, you can also use [Pydev](http://pydev.org/). I've had some experience of this plugin and found it pretty handy.

Comment: Odd; even after I install the DLTK Mylyn integration and the DLTK JavaScript IDE, individual functions aren't added to my task's context. It seems like there's no difference between using the WTP JavaScript editor and the DLTK JavaScript editor as far as Mylyn is concerned.